# How to access to form variables created by reflection c#

Tags: c#, reflection

Hi guys I´m trying to set a form variable that was created like this

```
var type = Type.GetType("namespace." + "formName");
Form form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;
```

The varible was created in the form designer

```
public int myVariable = 0;
```

What a I roughly want it to do is something like form.variable = 7
I tried this:

```
form.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(form, 7, null);
```

But it doesn't work :(

[image: This is the variable that I want to set]

**EDIT**
Sorry guys if didn't explain myself, I'll try to be more specific

```
        private void ShowForm(string frmname, string propertyName, int propertyValue)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType("RetailSystem.Compras." + frmname);
        Form form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;

        if (form != null)
        {
            // Set variables
            form.Show();
        }            
    }
```

This function will recieve a string which is the name of the form

Comment: Once you have your instance, it's pretty much a regular object; you don't need to keep using reflection to alter it's state. I.e., as suggested by Olivier: `form.myVariable = 7;` should do just fine.

Comment: @Llama I'm sorry I don't know what I am using, I'm noob in C#, I've searching on google for answer to achive my problem, but yes... I want to do exactly what you are saying, create an instance of a form by string and then set its variables

Comment: By the way, the icon next to `idAnalisisCompras` indicates that it's a field, not a property. See the icon explanations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Oh, and @Llama is right: that's a field, so GetProperty should return null. You'd have to use GetField if you needed (which you don't) to alter the value through reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's throw this into an answer to be clear.
Once you have your instance, it's pretty much a regular object; you don't need to keep using reflection to alter it's state. I.e., as suggested by Olivier: `form.myVariable = 7;` should do just fine.
Besides, the icon suggests that `idAnalisisCompras` is a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), not a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), so you'd have to use [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=net-5.0) if you needed to alter the value through reflection:

```
form.GetType().GetField(propertyName).SetValue(form, 7, null);
```

Looking at your edit, it seems like you want a function that instantiates a form and sets a given property/field to a value. If you don't know beforehand if you'll receive a property or a field to set, you'll have to check if GetProperty returns null, and then go for GetField. You could do so by [null coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) the results.

```
private void ShowForm(string frmname, string propertyName, int propertyValue)
{
    var type = Type.GetType("RetailSystem.Compras." + frmname);
    Form form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;

    if (form != null)
    {
        var PropOrField = form.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) 
             ?? form.GetType().GetField(propertyName);
        if(PropOrField is null)
        {
          //propertyName isn't a property nor a field on your form.
        }
        form.Show();
    }            
}
```

This is all pretty darn hacky and seems to point to deeper design problems.

Comment: that actually work , thank you to all you guys, I'm sorry if I could explain myself in the first place... English it's not my first language... 
Thank you!

Comment: NP, Eric. By your variables' names, I guess you're a spanish native. If so, ¡saludos!

Comment: De hecho si, Saludos hermano y gracias por tu tiempo!